# How to set any value to interface{}

Tags: go

I have following code:

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
)

type Point struct {
    x,y int
}

func decode(value interface{}) {
    fmt.Println(value) // -> &{0,0}

    // This is simplified example, instead of value of Point type, there
    // can be value of any type.
    value = &Point{10,10}
}

func main() {
    var p = new(Point)
    decode(p)

    fmt.Printf("x=%d, y=%d", p.x, p.y) // -> x=0, y=0, expected x=10, y=10
}
```

I want to set value of any type to the value passed to `decode` function. Is it possible in Go, or I misunderstand something?

http://play.golang.org/p/AjZHW54vEa

Comment: Go is pass-by-value. Assigning something to a local variable never affects the outside. You can use a reference type (like a pointer) to mutate the thing it points to in order to share state; but then it would need to a pointer of the right type in order for you to assign something to the thing it points to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generically, only [using reflection](http://play.golang.org/p/uMUOjvIs0c):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Point struct {
    x, y int
}

func decode(value interface{}) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(value)
    for v.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
        v = v.Elem()
    }
    n := reflect.ValueOf(Point{10, 10})
    v.Set(n)
}

func main() {
    var p = new(Point)
    decode(p)
    fmt.Printf("x=%d, y=%d", p.x, p.y)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure of your exact goal.

If you want to [assert](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) that `value` is a pointer to `Point` and change it, you can do that :

```
func decode(value interface{}) {
    p := value.(*Point)
    p.x=10
    p.y=10
}
```

Comment: you can also change an existing point with `p := value.(*Point); *p = Point{20, 20}`

Comment: @newacct Hum... you're totally right... I cleaned my answer. But as I still don't get what was the real intent of OP, I may remove the whole answer in a few days.